# Can you please provide references to learn about Fourier expansions for vector- valued functions?

Tags: reference-request

I am reading a paper by Peter Lax about the stability and convergence of finite difference schemes, and I need to understand a bit better the theory behind Fourier expansions for vector-valued functions. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I suppose the answer would depend on the kind of vector space you’re dealing with.

Comment: complex vector-valued functions